# How to remove &ZeroWidthSpace; from wiki pages

Tags: sharepoint-server, jquery, 2016, wiki-pages

I am using SharePoint 2016 wiki library. I have created several pages and they need to have same format. However, in some pages, SharePoint have inserted `&ZeroWidthSpace;` character at top of page. When browse with Chrome browser it looks like a link break and all the content move down by 1 line.

The problem is this `&ZeroWidthSpace;` is inserted inconsistently. Some page have `&ZeroWidthSpace` while some did not. The wiki pages format are inconsistent. I have tried modifying the content again and again but couldn't figure out the pattern of SharePoint insert `&ZeroWidthSpace;`.

How can I work around it? JQuery is acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

End up I replace the `&ZeroWidthSpace;` character with following JQuery. I have a `<div>` element with ID "tab":

```
if ($("#tab").length){
    $("#tab").html($("#tab").html().replace(/\u200B/g,""));
};
```